# Consecutive numbers filtering

Tags: filtering

I have a text file with a lot of number combinations.
It looks like this:

1 2 3 4 5 6

1 2 3 4 5 7

1 2 3 4 5 8

1 2 3 4 5 9

1 2 3 4 5 10

...

And so on...

Every line has **6** numbers with a space between each number.
Numbers go from **1 to 37.**

I need a way to remove all the lines **WITH AND MORE than 3 consecutive numbers,** in example:

**1 2 3** 13 28 35 **is not allowed.**

**1 2 3 4** 28 35 **is not allowed.**

**1 2 3 4 5** 35 **is not allowed.**

**1 2 3 4 5 6** **is not allowed.**

1 **7 8 9** 24 30 **is not allowed either.**

1 3 5 7 **10 11** **will be allowed.**

5 8 14 23 30 37 **will be allowed as well.**

**Special example:**

**1 2** 9 **15 16** 32 is allowed.

You got my point...

So, I need a way to do it, perhaps a code or something with instructions how to use it.

**Thanks!**

Comment: What coding language do you want to use? Grab all the numbers on the line, loop through and check if (x + 1) = n(next number) if it's true 3 times in a row remove the row.

Comment: What's the current behavior of your code? What's different between what's expected and what's happening? Please see the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page.

Comment: Upvoters: this question does not meet the criteria of SO questions. While downvoting may/may not be appropriate (different discussion), upvoting is clearly not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following awk command:

```
awk '($1 + 1 != $2 || $2 + 1 != $3) && ($2 + 1 != $3 || $3 + 1 != $4) && ($3 + 1 != $4 || $4 + 1 != $5) && ($4 + 1 != $5 || $5 + 1 != $6)' < input_file
```

Comment: I might have chosen something even more obscure, but this seems like a reasonable response. I'd upvote twice if I could.

Comment: Hi Tim, thanks for answering.
Sorry for the dumb question, but, how do I use it?

Comment: @Ryan: you would normally run this from your terminal. If that's an unfamiliar concept to you, check out: https://swcarpentry.github.io/shell-novice/01-intro/index.html

Comment: I am trying to run the following command:
awk '!(($1 + 1 == $2 && $2 + 1 == $3)  ($2 + 1 == $3 && $3 + 1 == $4)  ($3 + 1 == $4 && $4 + 1 == $5) || ($4 + 1 == $5 && $5 + 1 == $6))' < /c/Users/Ryan/Desktop/Part_1.txt > /c/Users/Ryan/Desktop/Result.txt

All I get is a blank text file on my desktop.

Comment: @Ryan: There are missing operators in that command you invoked. Make sure you copied and pasted it exactly.

Comment: I think I copied it exactly as you typed:
https://i.postimg.cc/Mpvg2mdJ/Capture.png

Comment: @Ryan: There are missing or (`||`) operators.

Comment: Oh my god, my bad, really sorry...
Now I get all the numbers, but, not in a separate lines, what should I do?

Comment: @Ryan: They are on separate lines, but if you are opening the output file with a program that does not understand `\n` line endings (e.g. Windows notepad), it might not appear that way. If you have the `unix2dos` command installed, you can run: `awk .... < input_file.txt | unix2dos > output_file.txt` and then open the output file.

Comment: It's working! Thank you so much, I really appreciate your help and patience :)

Comment: @Ryan: You're welcome. Please remember to [accept answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) that answer your question.

Comment: @TimCooper  Hi Tim, may I get another awk command to remove 2 and 3 pairs?

Comment: @Ryan: Please post another question and reference this one as your starting point.

Comment: @TimCooper Hi, last question got locked.
I opened another one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57806614/removing-lines-with-consecutive-pairs