# Removing lines with consecutive pairs

Tags: awk, numbers, filtering

I have a text file with a lot of number combinations. It looks like this:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6
1 2 3 4 5 7
1 2 3 4 5 8
1 2 3 4 5 9
1 2 3 4 5 10
```

Every line has 6 numbers with a space between each number. Numbers go from 1 to 37.

I need an AWK command to remove any line with 2 or 3 consecutive pairs.

For example:

**1 2** 6 9 **13 14**

**4 5 18 19 25 26**

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '{pairs = 0; for (i = 1; i < NF; i++) if ($i + 1 == $(i + 1)) pairs++; if (pairs != 2 && pairs != 3) print}' input_file
```

Comment: here the pairs overlap.  Not sure it's the OP's intention.  I think `1 2 3 4` should be two pairs, but your script will count three.